# Cómo puedo paginar una tabla con JavaScript sin acceder a internet?

Tags: javascript, html5

Cómo podría paginar una tabla con JavaScript sin acceder a internet?

Esto es el código que llevo hasta ahora:

```
<table id="embarazadas" style="background: white" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
                    <caption>Registro</caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No. HE</th>
                            <th>Nombrey apellidos</th>
                            <th>CI</th>
                            <th>F. Diagn&oacute;stico</th>
                            <th>Grupo de riesgo</th>
                            <th>Doctor/a a cargo</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="fila">
                            <td>00</td>
                            <td>Ana Isabel Cobas Fresneda</td>
                            <td>88123456789</td>
                            <td>10/2/2018</td>
                            <td>Sobre-peso</td>
                            <td>Anaisa Fresneda Figuera</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="editUser btn btn-success">Editar</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="deleteUser  btn btn-warning">Eliminar</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="fila">
                            <td>01</td>
                            <td>Ana Mar&iacute;a Cobas Fresneda</td>
                            <td>89123456789</td>
                            <td>10/2/2018</td>
                            <td>Sobre-peso</td>
                            <td>Anaisa Fresneda Figuera</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="editUser btn btn-success">Editar</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="deleteUser  btn btn-warning">Eliminar</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="fila">
                            <td>02</td>
                            <td>Isabel Cobas Ford</td>
                            <td>90123456789</td>
                            <td>10/2/2018</td>
                            <td>Sobre-peso</td>
                            <td>Anaisa Fresneda Figuera</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="editUser btn btn-success">Editar</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="deleteUser  btn btn-warning">Eliminar</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="fila">
                            <td>03</td>
                            <td>Ana Isabel Cobas Fresneda</td>
                            <td>88123456789</td>
                            <td>10/2/2018</td>
                            <td>Sobre-peso</td>
                            <td>Anaisa Fresneda Figuera</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="editUser btn btn-success">Editar</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="deleteUser  btn btn-warning">Eliminar</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="fila">
                            <td>04</td>
                            <td>Ana Mar&iacute;a Cobas Fresneda</td>
                            <td>89123456789</td>
                            <td>10/2/2018</td>
                            <td>Sobre-peso</td>
                            <td>Anaisa Fresneda Figuera</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="editUser btn btn-success">Editar</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="deleteUser  btn btn-warning">Eliminar</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="fila">
                            <td>05</td>
                            <td>Isabel Cobas Ford</td>
                            <td>90123456789</td>
                            <td>10/2/2018</td>
                            <td>Sobre-peso</td>
                            <td>Anaisa Fresneda Figuera</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="editUser btn btn-success">Editar</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="deleteUser  btn btn-warning">Eliminar</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="fila">
                            <td>06</td>
                            <td>Ana Isabel Cobas Fresneda</td>
                            <td>88123456789</td>
                            <td>10/2/2018</td>
                            <td>Sobre-peso</td>
                            <td>Anaisa Fresneda Figuera</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="editUser btn btn-success">Editar</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="deleteUser  btn btn-warning">Eliminar</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="fila">
                            <td>07</td>
                            <td>Ana Mar&iacute;a Cobas Fresneda</td>
                            <td>89123456789</td>
                            <td>10/2/2018</td>
                            <td>Sobre-peso</td>
                            <td>Anaisa Fresneda Figuera</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="editUser btn btn-success">Editar</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="deleteUser  btn btn-warning">Eliminar</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="fila">
                            <td>08</td>
                            <td>Isabel Cobas Ford</td>
                            <td>90123456789</td>
                            <td>10/2/2018</td>
                            <td>Sobre-peso</td>
                            <td>Anaisa Fresneda Figuera</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="editUser btn btn-success">Editar</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="deleteUser  btn btn-warning">Eliminar</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

Comment: y cual sería tu problema?

Comment: descarga local las librerías y haces referencia a ellas en tus enlaces en lugar de llamar la web, https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/paginacion-jquery/

Comment: podrias usar [datatable](https://datatables.net/download/)

Comment: Podrías ser más específico con tu problema? Puedes comentarnos más acerca de lo que nos estás mostrando? Sin esto no podremos darte una respuesta de calidad o incluso ayudarte. Te invito a leer el siguiente artículo: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Se trata de una pagina donde debo mostrar datos de embarazadas (los que estan en las tablas solo son un ejemplo de lo que se debe llenar), soy nueva en esti de programacion de paginas web encontre algunos plugin de como paginar las tablas pero no me servian(lo mas seguro es que no halla sabido utilizarlos correctamente) o necesitaba archivos desde internet(los descargaba pero lo mas seguro es que no suiera utilizarlos corectamente) y despues de buscar por varios dias una respuesta encontre este sitio mi problema principal se basa en no saber utilizar correctamente los componentes de las web